# SQLDependency cannot be registered SqlNotificationEventArgs.Info is returned with Invalid status

Tags: c#, sql-server, caching, ncache

I am using NCache on my applications with SQLDependency.

When I add items to the cache, there aren't any errors and the code continues, but really is not added anything to the cache.

Looking at the NCache logs, I see this ERROR message:

> SQLDependency cannot be registered SqlNotificationEventArgs.Info is returned with Invalid status

but there aren't any detail.

Any help?

Comment: There are a [number of restrictions on the query used for notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v=sql.105)), such as session `SET` options, 2-part names, single statement, etc. Add your query if you need help troubleshooting.

Comment: The problems seems that we are using a TEXT column in our query, we have change that datatype and now works.